# Is the text of the New Vulgate protected by copyright?

Tags: copyright, translation

Recently there was a question on the [Latin Language Stack Exchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com) website about different translations of the Bible, I am considering editing some passages in the form of a comparison between the different versions (one column per translation).

Is the New Vulgate copyrighted or can I use it freely?
I have not found any information on this subject in the [CONSTITUTIO APOSTOLICA](https://www.vatican.va/archive/bible/nova_vulgata/documents/nova-vulgata_jp-ii_apost_const_lt.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vatican copyright law](https://www.vaticanstate.va/phocadownload/leggi-decreti/normativa-altre-materie/Legge%20N.%20CXCVII%20All.%2025.pdf) article 5 says

> 1. Spetta alla Santa Sede ed allo Stato della Città del Vaticano il diritto di autore sulle opere create o pubblicate sotto il loro nome o
>    realizzate per loro conto.
>
> § 2. Ai fini della presente legge per Santa Sede si intendono, oltre
> al Romano Pontefice, i Dicasteri e gli Organismi della Curia Romana,
> nonché le Istituzioni ad essa collegate.
>
> § 3. A ciascuno dei soggetti di cui al paragrafo 2, che siano dotati
> di autonomia amministrativa nel quadro della normativa generale o
> dello statuto proprio, sono affidati l'esercizio e la tutela del
> diritto di autore nelle materie di rispettiva competenza.
>
> § 4. La durata dei diritti esclusivi di utilizzazione economica che
> spettano ai soggetti di cui ai paragrafi precedenti è stabilita in
> settanta anni a partire dall'anno di prima pubblicazione dell'opera,
> qualunque sia la forma nella quale la pubblicazione è stata
> effettuata, ovvero dall'anno di morte dell'autore ove questi sia
> indicato nell’opera

§4 is the crucial time limit: 70 years from publication:

> The duration of the exclusive rights of economic use belonging to the
> subjects referred to in the preceding paragraphs is established in
> seventy years starting from the year of first publication of the work,
> whatever the form in which the publication was made, or from the year
> of death of the author where this is indicated in the work

Under [Italian copyright law](https://wipolex.wipo.int/en/text/477668) article 29,

> The duration of the exploitation rights belonging, under art. 11, to
> the State, the provinces, the communes, the academies or public
> cultural organizations, or to private legal entities of a non-profit
> making character, shall be twenty years from first publication,
> whatever the form in which publication was effected. In the case of
> communications and memoranda published by academies and other public
> cultural organizations, the term shall be reduced to two years, after
> which the author shall wholly recover his right to the unrestricted
> disposal of his writings.

While Italian copyright law generally holds in Vatican City, it does do only when not contradicted by Vatican law. The across-the-board 70 year copyright is a clear indication of an exception regarding duration (indeed, it also allows perpetual copyright for writings of popes).

Also noting that Italian copyright law does not have a "fair use" exception, we can conclude that the work is and will be protected for some years.

Comment: Amazing find, thank you very much!